# How difficult this RSA cracking algorithm is.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

If the way to crack the RSA algorithm is knowing the factors of a number. How easy can the factors be obtained by taking the reverse 'long product'?.

For instance, if you have the product of three digit numbers(letters for place value) abc * def = ghijk, why can't the last digit k give possible quotients?(1-digit numbers that when multiplyed give last digit as k) These two numbers give the possible numbers that can be multiplied to be added to give j and so on.

How complicated will this constrained tree grow? How is this method complex?

Comment: Your algorithm amounts to solving $n \equiv pq \pmod{10}$, which gives choices for $p \pmod{10}$ and $q \pmod{10}$. If you know $p \pmod{10}$ and $q \pmod{10}$ you can then repeat the same thing with the next digit. But for each digit there will be multiple choices, and the total number of choices grows exponentially with the number of digits. The best general-purpose algorithm for integer factorization now is the General number field sieve ([GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)). This is subexponential in the number of digits, but still slower than polynomial.

Comment: If it is easy by reversing the long product, try to find the whole square of _(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)_, where each letter represents a digit.

Comment: @severnkariuki: You might want to look up the "Integer Factorization Problem".

Comment: We can say more by modulus modulo 12 than we can with this.

Comment: How about generating a table of each product of each pair of primes?